# invertir el orden de una linea de texto

Tags: python

cómo puedo invertir el orden de las palabras en una linea de texto?. Por ejemplo: "Hola, como están ustedes" por "ustedes están como Hola,".

por favor en python.

Comment: Hola Lenin, te doy la bienvenida a [es.so]. ¿Has intentado algo para resolver el problema? Si es así deberías agregarlo a la pregunta para demostrar el trabajo previo requerido por las normas del sitio. Si no has intentado nada, mirate el método `str.split()`, te permite separar la cadena en fragmentos según el separador que indiques y los mete en una lista. Luego basta con usar `list.reverse` por ejemplo y `str.join` para obtener una nueva cadena. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para invertir una línea de texto por palabras, debes primero partirla por el separador de palabras ' ' con `str.split()`. La lista resultante puede ser reversada (inline, es decir un método sobre el mismo objeto que no retorna valor) con `list.reverse()`. finalmente debes unir las palabras con un separador (operación opuesta a `str.split()`, ten en cuenta que esta es llamada sobre el str separador en lugar de una lista).

Ejemplo completo:

```py
>>> initial = "Hola, cómo están ustedes?"
>>> temp = initial.split(' ')
>>> temp
['Hola,', 'cómo', 'están', 'ustedes?']
>>> temp.reverse()
>>> print(temp)
['ustedes?', 'están', 'cómo', 'Hola,']
>>> final = ' '.join(temp)
>>> final
'ustedes? están cómo Hola,'
```

Dejo como ejercicio el lidiar con las las mayúsculas, comas y las tildes.

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Comment: A mi parecer responder preguntas donde claramente no se cumplen las normas y no se ve un mínimo esfuerzo previo no ayuda al sitio. Veo que tienes poca puntuación y por lo tanto eres nuevo, por favor revisa las normas de la web y verás que se fomentan dos cosas, que la gente pregunte sin miedo,sea cual su nivel pero también que la pregunta sea de valor y muestre un esfuerzo previo por parte del que pregunta, pues si no, básicamente le hacemos los deberes. Un saludo.

Comment: Cómo el sitio está creciendo, prefiero responder a preguntas a pesar de que no cumplan con todas las características de una buena pregunta. Espero crear comunidad así y entre todos mejorar el sitio en lugar de tener un sitio muy curado pero poco activo. IMO

Comment: Además creo que si era para una tarea, le he dejado un ejercicio bueno todavía ;)